# I am trying to run a if-else condition in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here i am trying to get fields using if else condition:

```js
if (typeof dataType === "textArea") {
    operator.concat('Equals', 'Does Not Equals');
} else {
    operator.concat('Equals', 'Does Not Equals','Greater than equal to','Greater Than','Less Than','Less than equal to');
}
```

But it is not working. Can anyone suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: Best you explain more what you are doing here i.e. what does `dataType` contain? Note that `typeof` only returns the basic datatypes of JavaScript e.g. "number".

Comment: well dataType contains all the name of fields in a particular sobject.i have to render that sobject on the basis of textarea and number datatype

Comment: Is `dataType` an array? If it is then e.g. `if (dataType.includes('textArea')) {`.

Comment: yes it is an array

Comment: well can you please tell me the whole syntax once??

Comment: `if (dataType.includes('textArea')) {` replaces `if (typeof dataType === "textArea") {`.